# Change pagination link

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a page in WordPress where I make an API call to generate some data. I have a form with `method="get"` and when the user type in a keyword it makes a request and generates a response. Now, to create pagination I need to pass another param in query string `&page=2`.

The problem is when I do that WordPress formats URL and instead: `?keyword=something&page=2` the URL becomes: `/2/?keyword=something`.

Is there a way to keep the query string with `&page=2`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $args = array(
    'base'               => '%_%',
    'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
    'total'              => 1,
    'current'            => 0,
    'show_all'           => false,
    'end_size'           => 1,
    'mid_size'           => 2,
    'prev_next'          => true,
    'prev_text'          => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'          => __('Next »'),
    'type'               => 'plain',
    'add_args'           => false,
    'add_fragment'       => '',
    'before_page_number' => '',
    'after_page_number'  => ''
); ?>
```

Above are the default arguments available for wordpress paginate.

In order to pass the page as a query string you can pass it to

> 'add_args' => array( 'page' => 'page number','keyword' => 'something')

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. At the end i was able to get the `page` query param with `get_query_var('page')` and pass it to API call. That way i don't need to reformat URL.